# Execution time exceeded

Tags: php, algorithm

I am trying to find the sum of all primes below 2000000 and here is my code:

```
$set = 0;
for($i = 1; $i < 2000000; $i++){
    if(is_prime($i)){
        $set += $i;
    }
}

echo $set;
```

is_prime is the custom function i created to find whether the number is prime or not. The problem is it is taking too much time to execute. Any way to optimize it?

Answer (score 2):

Tell PHP not to time out using set_time_limit in seconds( 0 means infinite)

```
 set_time_limit(0);
```

also your loop in not efficient, a prime other than 2 cannot be even , so you should be stepping up with + 2 and add 2 to the starting $set

```
$set = 2

for($i = 1; $i < 2000000; $i += 2)
```

Code:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

$set = 2;  // 2 is a prime number so must be included in the set

for($i = 1; $i < 2000000; $i += 2){
    if(is_prime($i)){
        $set += $i;
    }
}

echo $set;
?>
```

Comment: Do not forget to start with `set = 2`if you loop only over the odd values.

Comment: no because $i is the loop count and the prime number and is already set at 1 , $set is the result

Comment: If you want to sum up all primes and loop only over the odd values, you miss the prime `2`. Therefore you have to initialize your sum with 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `is_prime($i)`-method is the bottleneck.

You can calculate all prime numbers (offline) up to 2000000 by using a [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to store all primes in 2000000 bits (or if you only store the odd numbers: 1000000) that fits in the RAM and makes `is_prime($i)`  `O(1)` time.